# prevent multiple user log-in for same user

Tags: java, desktop

I want know that how to prevent multiple user log-in for same user in my java desktop application. e.g. : if user-1 already logged in to database and he's trying to log in from another LAN computer, I want to show him a message that "you are already logged in".

Comment: it depends on the software components you are using. Some security frameworks offer this functionality out-of-the-box (apache shiro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such logic is very hard to maintain as you deal with lost of problem, and current trend of programming show that having an application on multiple device is standard procedure.

But if you really want to do that. You will have to implement two task.

First task will notifies the server that client is up. 
Second will traverse the list of logged in users and remove those that last sign of live is older than some time value.

This solution will protect you when, client is closed abnormal or do not have connection to server.

Off course you should remove the users from its list, when application is closed.

Comment: depends on the application. For multiplayer games for example you don't want multiple simultaneous logins from the same account (though you would still want one login to the game proper, another to the account website, a third to the support forums, etc. etc.).

Answer (score 1):

There is simple logic. Keep a track of login and logout into database. During login check the database. If user already in login then show the message otherwise logged him and mark the database he is in logged in untill logout..

Comment: I tried this method, but if application or PC shut down unexpectedly, then conflicts arises.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a web application then you can do it using session but here you can manage map i.e `Map<LoggedInUser>`  if user logged in app then put the user entry inside map and remove if user logout. if same user tries second time without logout then check map entry for him if entry found , show message 'YOU ARE ALLREADY LOGGED IN"  otherwise allow him to login.